# Submitting HTML characters to a Data Extension via Landing Page and SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I have tried to push data to data extension through a landing page using SSJS. The form fields contain HTML characters (which will **import** to the Data Extension fine). I'm getting this error when I submit the form:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
```

The error is being thrown because some of these fields contains < and > characters.

I am wondering if there is a way to replace those characters before submitting, or encode them in some way prior to entering the data extension?  I know AMPscript has a Replace function, but I'm not sure how I can use it within SSJS to achieve what I'm after.

Is there a Replace function, or something similar within SSJS?  Or another way to approach submitting these fields to the data extension?

Answer (score 0):

Base64Decode() is available in SSJS. You would have to encode before sending in.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/utilities_server_side_javascript_functions/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace function in SSJS as you would do in AMPScript.

I would say the urlencoding function is the right one for encoding, so it stays sort of human-readable in the DE and can be shown on e.g. a cloudpage.

```js
<script type="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1")
var yourinput = "<html></html>";
yourinput = yourinput.replace("<","%3C");
yourinput = yourinput.replace(">","%3E");
Write(yourinput);
</script>
```

outputs:

```
%3Chtml%3E
```

See https://www.urldecoder.org/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar custom application, after some R&D I came up with this approach.

You can also use this approach to pass HTML/XML code from an external application to Marketing Cloud's Landing page.

1) Use the below function to Encode your INPUT field which have your HTML codes.

> **Encoding** using `window.btoa()` method.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('Contentblock').onsubmit = function() 
         {
             var t = window.btoa(document.getElementById('Email_HTML').value);
             document.getElementById('Email_HTML').value = t;
         }
</script>
```

2) Use the below SSJS function to Decode your request parameter from HTML form.

> **Decode** using `Platform.Function.Base64Decode()` method.

```js
var Email_HTML = Platform.Function.Base64Decode(Platform.Request.GetFormField('Email_HTML'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this, but see my answer on this post.

[AMPscript to decode HTML entity in data extension field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80357/ampscript-to-decode-html-entity-in-data-extension-field/378033#378033)